# My Prestashop is slow - how can I make it faster?

Tags: performance, prestashop

My company is using PrestaShop 1.4.9.0, and we have ~ 170000 products in database, ~3000 clients, ~5000 orders. We have around 50 visitors in same time, but we expect 4-8 times more for the next weeks.

What can you suggest to improve the time of response on this PrestaShop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Cache` in `Performance` and put it to `Memcached` for example if it's not already. Also use a `PHP Profiler` to check the performance and resolve any issues according to the results. There's also a very important point which is the slow performance of the function `file_exists`

[PS validator](http://validator.prestashop.com) insists on replacing `file_exists` with `Tools::file_exists_cache`

```
/**
 * file_exists() wrapper with cache to speedup performance
 *
 * @param string $filename File name
 * @return boolean Cached result of file_exists($filename)
 */

protected static $file_exists_cache = array();

public static function file_exists_cache($filename)
{
    if (!isset(self::$file_exists_cache[$filename]))
        self::$file_exists_cache[$filename] = file_exists($filename);
    return self::$file_exists_cache[$filename];
}
```

This code is from PS1.6 and should be added to `Tools` class in `classes/Tools.php`, if you found that the method already exists, just replace it

Anyway, the profiler is the key to resolve such problems
I personally use [`PHPed Profiler`](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_profiler.htm) (commercial)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the DEBUG mode and Prestashop will show you any installed module and its load time. Then you can locate what module is slowing down your shop.

To enable the DEBUGGING mode go to 'config/defines.inc.php' and change the line:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

To 'true'.